# Lost and found on Cycladic islands

Tags: greece

On a hike yesterday my girlfriend and I found a watch that could have considerable value to someone on one of the smaller Cycladic islands in Greece. We've been asking around whether somebody reported it as lost. At the police station we've been told reluctantly that they would keep it until the owner claims it or a year passes. We are not convinced this would help, because they seem to lack any kind of lost & found infrastructure. Does somebody know of any alternatives?

Comment: Police is the right place. Think about the person who lost it. He would check probably to police (also because maybe he needs some proof for insurance). Ferry line could be an alternative, but because police was reluctant without telling you alternative, I think there are no alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone who has found a lost thing must notify the person who lost it or another beneficiary or the police authority within 14 days (10 days in case of finding a Police Identity Card). Failure to do so is a criminal offense.

The Police Department is required to draw up a finding voucher with the details of the finder.

The finder is entitled to request a reward from the beneficiary. After one year from the notification of the police authority and provided that the beneficiary has not been found, the finder acquires the ownership of the thing.

If the finder does not receive the item he / she is entitled to within the time specified by the police authority, the ownership shall be transferred to the municipality of the place where the thing was found.

Anyone who has found a thing in a residential building or in an area intended for the use of the public (eg an airport) must hand it over to the owner of the building or to the lessee or to the person in charge of the site. In this case, the person to whom the thing was delivered is considered to be the finder.

Sources: Articles from 1081 to 1093 of Greek Civil Law, see [here](https://www.lawspot.gr/nomikes-plirofories/nomothesia/astikos-kodikas) or [here](http://www.freelaw.gr/ak).

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE and thanks for your contribution! Could you add some sources to back up your answer, e.g. links to the respective rules (English is best but Greek will be just fine)?

Comment: Articles  from 1081 to 1093 of Greek Civil Law [link] https://www.lawspot.gr/nomikes-plirofories/nomothesia/astikos-kodikas[/link] or [link]http://www.freelaw.gr/ak[/link]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I took the freedom to incorporate these links into your answer, as they can get lost when a comment is deleted. +1

Comment: Thank you all, that's a very clear and thorough answer!